# free rtos raspberry pi

Tags: software-installation, freertos

I have downloaded freertos and unable run the make file. It's showing error as

```
Make:usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ gcc command not found
```

What is this?

Comment: you need to install gcc first... It's probably `sudo apt-get install gcc` but you can google "raspberry pi install gcc" to find out more.

Comment: I have a feeling FreeRTOS doesn't us apt. You might have to install from source. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442211/compiling-freertos-with-gcc-app-code-with-g

Answer (score 1):

This means the `gcc` command is not found. `gcc` is the Gnu Compiler Collection and it is (a bit simplified) used by make to compile the source code into binaries that the system can run.

Depending on what host system you are compiling this on, there are different ways to install `gcc`. Consult documentation for your operating system.

There is a [post](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/April_2005/freertos_Installing_GCC_for_ARM_1271499.html) concerning this on the FreeRTOS support forum.